# loop through string and print out results on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a Python program that outputs a single line of a chain of commands that I can copy into a Linux shell to execute.

I want the format to look like this:

> Command1; Command2; Command3; Command4; etc....

Here is my Python:

```
data = dict(
    Food_Title=foodFileTitle,
    Local_Store_Directory='/mnt/store/1/',
    Local_Unique_Directory='current/')

commands = """\
    mkdir -p {Local_Store_Directory}{Local_Unique_Directory}{Food_Title};
    """

# loop through commands and execute
for command in commands.splitlines():
    command = command.format(**data)  # populate command
    # os.system(command) # execute command
    print(command)
```

The problem is that it looks like this:

```
    mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/ab45re;

    mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/hf22;

    mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/bi334;
```

Is there a way to get it to look like this?

```
    mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/ab45re; mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/hf22; mkdir -p /mnt/store/1/current/bi334;
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `end` value of `print()`. Such as:

```py
print(command, end=' ') # Can use ';' here if you want
```

If your `command` variable has newline characters in it (`'\n'`), you'll want to replace those first, try:

```py
print(command.replace('\n', ''), end=' ')
```